# How is the Internet divided in respect to routers finding paths to host/networks?

Tags: router, routing, routing-table

As it was answered in another question of mine (about something little different) by Baldrickk it looks "similar to sending a letter to another country - it is narrowed down by country, then region, then town, then street, then building. The internet is split up in a similar way. Each gateway reached will know what is on which side (routing tables) e.g. your router knows all 192.168.X.X addresses are on the LAN and routes messages to other IPs to the other side of the gateway. This happens across the whole internet." 
How do routers know to which "side" a packet should be forwarded? I mean there are millions of hosts and networks the Internet consist of, and obviously in an average routing table you won't find routes to *all* those networks.

Comment: You should study up on subnetting. Routers do not carry all the routes to all other networks in their routing tables. A router only needs to know the next hop, which is the router that knows where the other networks are. For instance, router A only needs to know that 140.x.x.x needs to go to router B. Router B might know that 140.10.x.x needs to go to Router C. But router A does not need to know 140.10.x.x goes to router C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the bottom are end network routers. These just know what's local and what's not. A typical small office or home router just knows that, say, 192.168.1.0/24 is local and everything else goes to the ISP's router.

At the very top are internet core routers. These do have a full internet routing table. They have large numbers of routes (around [three quarters of a million](http://www.cidr-report.org/as2.0/#General_Status) or so) but very little information about each route. These are the routers that handle large regional networks and routing between different internet service providers.

It's correct that the routes *do* get narrower: the global internet table only has broad routes pointing towards an ISP, but routers inside that ISP have much narrower routes for different regions and customers. Finally, once you reach the customer's own router, it will have even more specific routes for individual subnets. Therefore "full internet table" does not contain every single subnet in the world.

Routers that don't have a default route to a router "above" them to catch all the hundreds of thousands of networks do in fact have to have massive routing tables.

Comment: All though an oversimplification - there are lots of in-between size routers - and many have partial routing table with defaults - but this answer is "more-or-less" correct. It should be added that larger routers will often know multiple paths for a route and select "the best" (subjective to owners, and limited by protocol limitations) - Routing between networks uses the BGP protocol, which allows routers to know about more then just their immediate peers.